# dbml linq to sql connection string change in a silverlight application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, silverlight-5.0

I have a web application and using service reference to connect a ms sql-server database. When i try to initialize like application on a IIS7 websever the application doesn't receive data. When the connection string was modify in the web.config but it still doesn't work.

This application was developed in a closed area and initialized on IIS7 the application is running just this database connection doesn't work.

Comment: Post the connection section of web.config in your question.

Comment: '<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ConnstringName" connectionString="Data Source=SourceServerName;Initial Catalog=CName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pwd" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
</connectionStrings>'

It was a generated code and i just change the server address and username with password because it was changed